# Drupal /node redirect to <front> page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am not using the /node page on my site. When I visit the /node I get the default drupal text.

> Welcome to your new Drupal website!
>
> Please follow these steps to set up
>   and start using your website:
>
> Configure your websiteConfigure your website

I wish to send /node to my  page. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the admin, and go to the Site Information (/admin/settings/site-information). Change the site frontpage at the bottom to a node path of your choosing. This will set a new homepage. Nothing else needed.

Comment: I would also use hook_menu_alter() to nuke the /node page so visitors can't go looking for it.

Comment: The hook_menu_alter() was the bit I was missing.

Answer (score 7):

Thre is no setting for that. 
If you want to redirect to the frontpage, you will have to modify the `.htaccess` file with these lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^node(/)?$  / [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It will redirect node and node/ to the path / , i.e. frontpage

Comment: Way too much. No need to do this and might have other consequences.

Comment: Not too much. I answered her question "I wish to sent /node to my page." And I think is very valid answer. In the other hand, if she only wanted to redirect her homepage (/ URL) to other page, your answer is enough.

Comment: Agree with corbacho. This makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set a page as front page on your Drupal site. Do the following

```
Create Content -> Page -> Publish Options -> select promoted to front page
```

Comment: I have set a page as front page. The /node page still exists and be defaults lists all nodes published to front page. I don't need this page at all and just want to display the home page (which is of Page type).

Comment: I agree with Kevin's solution but if you want a role based front page setting then you need install <a href="http://drupal.org/project/front">front</a> module, read the README file.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way for those afraid of digging into the code is to simply and easily create a URL Alias for /node to /node/1 (or whatever node your home page is)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [Redirect module](https://drupal.org/project/redirect) and set up a 301 redirect for the /node page unless you want to play with your .htaccess file which is actually a better way to solve the issue.